# Proper use of DCOUNTA() in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to count data in my database using multiple criteria as in

```
=DCOUNTA(DatosBanderas;"MUNICIPIO";{{"Correcto";"=true"},{"Provincia";"=Barcelona"}})
```

I get `Formula parse error`. However, simpler queries as

```
 =DCOUNTA(DatosBanderas;"MUNICIPIO";{"Correcto";"=true"})
```

or

```
 =DCOUNTA(DatosBanderas;"MUNICIPIO";{"Provincia";"=Barcelona"})
```

do work. Using

```
=DCOUNTA(DatosBanderas;"MUNICIPIO";critrange)
```

with "critrange" a two by two cell range with contents "Provincia", "Correcto" in the top row and "Barcelona" and "true" in the bottom row also does work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`=DCOUNTA($A$1:$D$7;"MUNICIPIO";{{"Correcto";"TRUE"}\{"Provincia";"Barcelona"}})`

(for countries using decimal comma separators)

**OR**

`=DCOUNTA($A$1:$D$7,"MUNICIPIO",{{"Correcto";"TRUE"},{"Provincia";"Barcelona"}})`

(for countries using decimal point notation)

---

The condition is the value of the cell, so  it is:

- `"TRUE"` rather than `=true`, and
- `"Barcelona"`rather than `"=Barcelona"`

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks